# Displaying different list edit forms

Tags: 2013, list-form

I have two pages that use the same list with different columns displayed (from list columns `A, B, C, D, E`, page1 list view contains `A, B, C`; page2 list view contains `A, D, E`). The desired functionality is that whenever I edit a list item in one of these pages I use a different edit form.
Is there a way to display different list edit forms directly?
As far as I know, each list has a default new and edit forms assigned and creating an additional form requires switching through "Current View" to the desired edit form. What How can I make the edit form, that is not default to be opened by default?

What I have tried so far:
I have tried setting up two different content types, into one list, although I am not sure how to display and use content type discretely in one page or another.

I also stumbled into [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76949/different-list-forms-for-edit-and-new), although I am not sure how should I use an additional field for deducing the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new form using SharePoint Designer for your list "MyList", call the form  "MySecondEditForm". Then you can use link like `http://mysharepoint.com/Lists/MyList/MySecondEditForm.aspx?ID=[N]&Source=[S]` to access that form. Depending on how you display the list on the pages, you can use e.g., JSLink to add specific "Edit" button for each row containing the correct link.

- [N] needs to be the ID of the list item you would like to edit.
- You can also define [S] to be the URL user is redirected to after clicking OK/Cancel on the edit form.